# How to adjust row height based on content in one column and have overflowing text in the adjacent column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border-color: #f56565;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 5px solid BlueViolet;
  background: #000;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: #fff;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  flex: 1;
}

div>ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#list {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="list" class="child">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
      <li>J</li>
      <li>K</li>
      <li>L</li>
      <li>M</li>
      <li>N</li>
      <li>O</li>
      <li>P</li>
      <li>Q</li>
      <li>R</li>
      <li>S</li>
      <li>T</li>
      <li>U</li>
      <li>V</li>
      <li>W</li>
      <li>X</li>
      <li>Y</li>
      <li>Z</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="child">
    <h3 class="font-bold text-4xl">
      Title
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin feugiat malesuada orci, eu tristique libero tincidunt quis. Pellentesque ligula sem, volutpat non magna ac, mollis pretium sapien. Proin gravida urna in libero vestibulum, eget scelerisque
      tellus aliquet. Nunc sollicitudin arcu felis, vitae posuere ipsum semper nec. Pellentesque at urna vel ligula tincidunt cursus. Praesent vel risus molestie, consectetur metus eget, egestas nisi. Aenean elit nisl, fermentum nec purus id, condimentum
      rhoncus magna. Praesent neque nulla, consequat euismod dignissim ut, malesuada ac est. Suspendisse dapibus mi vitae finibus tempus. Fusce sed nibh ullamcorper, posuere ipsum eu, egestas justo. Suspendisse pharetra rhoncus maximus. Quisque a egestas
      lorem. Vestibulum scelerisque mollis fermentum. Duis id tortor et erat suscipit blandit. Vestibulum sed mollis nisl, ut scelerisque ligula.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm facing a layout challenge where I have a row containing two columns. The first column contains a list that may overflow and should be scrollable, while the second column contains dynamic content. I want the height of the row to be dictated by the content in the second column.

Edit: I added a snippet. I want #list to shorten to the height of #content, no ugly black bar (like it would do if #list was just a blank div without any text).

Comment: Show the html code that you have been using

Answer (score -1):

to create a layout where one column contains a scrollable list, and the other column contains dynamic content, with the row height determined by the dynamic content's height.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child list">
    <ul>
      <!-- Your list items here -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="child content">
    <!-- Your dynamic content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  border-color: #f56565;
  border: 5px solid BlueViolet;
  background: #000;
}

.child {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.list {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow from the content column */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Additional styles for the dynamic content */
.content h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem; /* Adjust as needed */
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```